# How to make a wide longtable fit on page?

Tags: tables, longtable, width, excel

I'm new to LaTeX, and copied over a table from Excel into TeXShop (mac) using the macro. I set it as a longtable because it spans two pages, but with regard to width, the table isn't fitting. 
Also, where can I insert the `\label` and `\caption` commands?

Here's the code I've used:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

    \title{}
        \author{}
        \date{}

    %This introduces packages that will be used in the text 
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    % lscape.sty Produce landscape pages in a (mainly) portrait document.
    \usepackage{lscape}

    %This sets new commands/shortcuts that can be used
    \newcommand{\ecoli}{\emph{Escherichia coli }}
    \newcommand{\PCMX}{Chloroxylenol }
    \newcommand{\potperm}{Potassium Permanganate}
    \newcommand{\mhagar}{Mueller-Hinton Agar}
    \newcommand{\sulfuricacid}{H$_2$SO$_4$}

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Blank Data Tables}
%Table generated by macro in TeXShop by copy-pasting table from Excel

\begin{longtable}{lllllllll}
No. & Juice & Loc. & Samp.No. & Dettol /mm$\pm$0.05 & Ethanol /mm$\pm$0.05 & 2M \sulfuricacid /mm$\pm$0.05 & H$^+$/KMnO$_4$ /mm$\pm$0.05 & Control/mm$\pm$0.05 \\
\endfirsthead
No. & Juice & Loc. & Samp.No. & Dettol /mm$\pm$0.05 & Ethanol /mm$\pm$0.05 & 2M \sulfuricacid /mm$\pm$0.05 & H$^+$/KMnO$_4$ /mm$\pm$0.05 & Control/mm$\pm$0.05 \\
\endhead
\multicolumn{9}{r}{{Continued\ldots}} \
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot

1 & Sugarcane & 1 & 1 \\
2 & Sugarcane & 1 & 2 \\
3 & Sugarcane & 1 & 3 \\
4 & Sugarcane & 1 & 4 \\
5 & Sugarcane & 1 & 5 \\
6 & Orange & 1 & 1 \\
7 & Orange & 1 & 2 \\
8 & Orange & 1 & 3 \\
9 & Orange & 1 & 4 \\
10 & Orange & 1 & 5 \\
11 & Carrot & 1 & 1 \\
12 & Carrot & 1 & 2 \\
13 & Carrot & 1 & 3 \\
14 & Carrot & 1 & 4 \\
15 & Carrot & 1 & 5 \\
16 & Sugarcane & 2 & 1 \\
17 & Sugarcane & 2 & 2 \\
18 & Sugarcane & 2 & 3 \\
19 & Sugarcane & 2 & 4 \\
20 & Sugarcane & 2 & 5 \\
21 & Orange & 2 & 1 \\
22 & Orange & 2 & 2 \\
23 & Orange & 2 & 3 \\
24 & Orange & 2 & 4 \\
25 & Orange & 2 & 5 \\
26 & Carrot & 2 & 1 \\
27 & Carrot & 2 & 2 \\
28 & Carrot & 2 & 3 \\
29 & Carrot & 2 & 4 \\
30 & Carrot & 2 & 5 \\
31 & Sugarcane & 3 & 1 \\
32 & Sugarcane & 3 & 2 \\
33 & Sugarcane & 3 & 3 \\
34 & Sugarcane & 3 & 4 \\
35 & Sugarcane & 3 & 5 \\
36 & Orange & 3 & 1 \\
37 & Orange & 3 & 2 \\
38 & Orange & 3 & 3 \\
39 & Orange & 3 & 4 \\
40 & Orange & 3 & 5 \\
41 & Carrot & 3 & 1 \\
42 & Carrot & 3 & 2 \\
43 & Carrot & 3 & 3 \\
44 & Carrot & 3 & 4 \\
45 & Carrot & 3 & 5 \\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning table size, you might put the unit and error on a second line, either by creating a second line of the table heading, like this:

```
No. & Juice & Loc. & Samp.No. & Dettol      & Ethanol     & 2M \sulfuricacid & H$^+$/KMnO$_4$ & Control \\
    &       &      &          & mm$\pm0.05$ & mm$\pm$0.05 & mm$\pm$0.05      & mm$\pm$0.05    & mm$\pm$0.05\\
```

or by using `\shortstack`, like this:

```
No. & Juice & Loc. & Samp.No. & \shortstack{Dettol\\mm$\pm$0.05} & \shortstack{Ethanol\\mm$\pm$0.05} & \shortstack{2M \sulfuricacid\\mm$\pm$0.05} & \shortstack{H$^+$/KMnO$_4$\\mm$\pm$0.05} & \shortstack{Control\\mm$\pm$0.05} \\
```

The `\caption` and `\label` can be used at the the begining (in this case, don't forget the `\\` after `\caption`) or at the end of the environment `longtable`, as you normally do with `table` or `figure`. In other words,

```
\begin{longtable}{lllllllll}
\caption{...}\label{...}\\
...
```

or

```
...
\caption{...}\label{...}
\end{longtable}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setup correctly, you have five columns whose units are measured in `/mm$\pm0.05$` (and for which you will probably use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package). You could move the information about the common units to a second row, tying this informaton to the five data columns via a `\cmidrule` that spans the data columns.

The following image, which shows just the table's header and first few rows, is deliberately not turn 90 degrees to landscape format in order to make it more easily readable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape,siunitx} % load just the packages needed for this MWE

    %This sets new commands/shortcuts that can be used
    \newcommand{\ecoli}{\emph{Escherichia coli }}
    \newcommand{\PCMX}{Chloroxylenol }
    \newcommand{\potperm}{Potassium Permanganate}
    \newcommand{\mhagar}{Mueller-Hinton Agar}
    \newcommand{\sulfuricacid}{H$_2$SO$_4$}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule, and \bottomrule macros

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Blank Data Tables}
%Table generated by macro in TeXShop by copy-pasting table from Excel

\begin{longtable}{llll *{5}{S[table-format=3.2]}} % set 'table-format' to suit your needs
\toprule
No. & Juice & Loc. & Samp.~No. & 
{Dettol}  & {Ethanol}  & {2M \sulfuricacid}  & {H$^+$/KMnO$_4$}  & {Control} \\
\cmidrule(l){5-9}
&&&& \multicolumn{5}{c}{[ /mm $\pm 0.05$ ]}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{9}{r@{}}{Continued \ldots} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

1 & Sugarcane & 1 & 1 \\
2 & Sugarcane & 1 & 2 \\
3 & Sugarcane & 1 & 3 \\
4 & Sugarcane & 1 & 4 \\
5 & Sugarcane & 1 & 5 \\
6 & Orange & 1 & 1 \\
7 & Orange & 1 & 2 \\
8 & Orange & 1 & 3 \\
9 & Orange & 1 & 4 \\
10 & Orange & 1 & 5 \\
11 & Carrot & 1 & 1 \\
12 & Carrot & 1 & 2 \\
13 & Carrot & 1 & 3 \\
14 & Carrot & 1 & 4 \\
15 & Carrot & 1 & 5 \\
16 & Sugarcane & 2 & 1 \\
17 & Sugarcane & 2 & 2 \\
18 & Sugarcane & 2 & 3 \\
19 & Sugarcane & 2 & 4 \\
20 & Sugarcane & 2 & 5 \\
21 & Orange & 2 & 1 \\
22 & Orange & 2 & 2 \\
23 & Orange & 2 & 3 \\
24 & Orange & 2 & 4 \\
25 & Orange & 2 & 5 \\
26 & Carrot & 2 & 1 \\
27 & Carrot & 2 & 2 \\
28 & Carrot & 2 & 3 \\
29 & Carrot & 2 & 4 \\
30 & Carrot & 2 & 5 \\
31 & Sugarcane & 3 & 1 \\
32 & Sugarcane & 3 & 2 \\
33 & Sugarcane & 3 & 3 \\
34 & Sugarcane & 3 & 4 \\
35 & Sugarcane & 3 & 5 \\
36 & Orange & 3 & 1 \\
37 & Orange & 3 & 2 \\
38 & Orange & 3 & 3 \\
39 & Orange & 3 & 4 \\
40 & Orange & 3 & 5 \\
41 & Carrot & 3 & 1 \\
42 & Carrot & 3 & 2 \\
43 & Carrot & 3 & 3 \\
44 & Carrot & 3 & 4 \\
45 & Carrot & 3 & 5 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```